# What's the best .NET library for OpenID and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, openid

I'm looking at using OpenID for my authentication scheme and wanted to know what the best .NET library is to use for MVC specific applications?

thx

Comment: Any specific criteria you looking for in defining which one is best?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[.Net OpenID project](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) is the best library to use right now that I know of.  I think SO used it also.  The source includes a sample ASP.NET MVC project using the library.

Scott Hanselman did a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) on how to use the .Net OpenID project inside of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Agreed, I just finished up my implementation and I used the DotNetOpenID project to get me going in ASP.NET MVC... http://regexhero.net/user/

Answer (score 2):

There's another library called [ExtremeSwank](http://extremeswank.com/aspnet_openid.html). This article by Andrew Arnott, a dotnetopenid developer, might also help you "[Why DotNetOpenID as your C# OpenID library of choice](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/04/why-dotnetopenid-as-your-c-openid.html)".

Comment: ExtremeSwank suffers from a fatal security flaw that lets anyone log in as anyone.  You can verify that on this test site: http://test-id.org/RP/IgnoresContentLocationHeader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We have been using .Net Open Id project and are pretty happy with it so far. Andrew Arnott does a great work of answering the queries and suggesting workarounds if you are struck. Give it a try and you will love it :)

Answer (score 0):

The project is shifted to http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/